# how to select an 192.168.3.0 from dropdown list (javascript) using jquery for test automation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the DOM. How do I select 192.168.3.0/24 using jquery?

```
<div id="s2id_dhcp-lease-xlan" class="select2-container xlans select2-container-active">
<a class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">
<span id="select2-chosen-1" class="select2-chosen">
<table style="width:100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="33%">LAN 1</td>
<td class="lightergrey group-hide" width="1%">Network: </td>
<td width="33%" style="line-height:100%">192.168.3.0/24</td>
<td class="lightergrey group-hide" width="1%">Default Gateway : </td>
<td width="30%">192.168.3.254</td>
<td class="lightergrey group-hide" width="1%">Type: </td>
<td width="1%">Ethernet</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</span>
<abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"/>
<span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation">
</a>
<label class="select2-offscreen" for="s2id_autogen1">Network</label>
<input id="s2id_autogen1" class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-1" aria-invalid="false"/>
</div>
```

I have got some existing method, but it's not applicable for this one.

```
public void selectEthernetIP(String ethernetIP) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("jQuery('#select2-chosen-1').select2('val', jQuery('#select2-chosen-1 option[data-network=\"" + bridgeDeviceList + "\"]').val())");
    }
```

Trying to do test automation on Selenium and need to select that particular IP from drop down list that' written using Javascript.

Comment: You should mention that you're using a jQuery plugin, Select 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ip = ($("#s2id_dhcp-lease-xlan").text()).match(/Network: \n(.*)\n/)[1];
```

Or in Selenium format:

```
public void selectEthernetIP(String ethernetIP) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("(jQuery('#s2id_dhcp-lease-xlan').text()).match(/Network: \n(.*)\n/)[1]");
}
```

Finally, it is not necessary to use jQuery in this call because we are using one simple ID selector:

```
public void selectEthernetIP(String ethernetIP) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("(document.getElementById('s2id_dhcp-lease-xlan').textContent).match(/Network: \n(.*)\n/)[1]");
}
```

Comment: would you please have it in this method format :

public void selectBridgeDeviceListNetworkSelection(String bridgeDeviceList) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("jQuery('#bridgeDeviceList').select2('val', jQuery('#bridgeDeviceList option[data-network=\"" + bridgeDeviceList + "\"]').val())");
    }
rather than using a var ip